# Scala : Sorting list of number based on another list

Tags: algorithm, scala, sorting, data-structures

I am implementing an algorithm in scala where I have set of nodes (Integers numbers) and each node has one property associated with it, lets call that property "d" (which is again an integer).

I have a list[Int] , this list contains nodes in the descending order of value "d".

Also I have a Map[Int,Iterable[Int]] , here key is a node and value is the list of all its neighbors.

The question is, how can I store the List of neighbors for a node in Map in the descending order of property "d" .

## Example :

List 1 : List[1,5,7,2,4,8,6,3]  --> Imagine this list is sorted in some order and has all the numbers.

Map : [Int,Iterable][Int]]  --> [1 , Iterable[2,3,4,5,6]]

This iterable may or may not have all numbers.

In simple words, I want the numbers in Iterable to be in same order as in List 1.

So my entry in Map should be : [1, Iterable[5,2,4,6,3]]

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question. Please add some unimplemented or pseudo-code with an example to demonstrate what you are looking for.

Comment: I have updated the question, hope it helps now.

Comment: How about `map.mapValues(neighbors => list.filter(neighbors.contains))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to just filter the sorted list.

```
val list = List(1,5,7,2,4,8,6,3)
val map = Map(1 -> List(2,3,4,5,6),
              2 -> List(1,2,7,8))
val map2 = map.mapValues(neighbors => list.filter(neighbors.contains))
println(map2)
```

Comment: This solution were well with my algorithm. Very time efficient as well.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution utilizing `foldLeft` (note we get an `ArrayBuffer` at end instead of desired `Iterable`, but the type signature does say `Iterable`):

```
scala> val orderTemplate = List(1,5,7,2,4,8,6,3)
orderTemplate: List[Int] = List(1, 5, 7, 2, 4, 8, 6, 3)

scala> val toOrder = Map(1 -> Iterable(2,3,4,5,6))
toOrder: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Iterable[Int]] = Map(1 -> List(2, 3, 4, 5, 6))

scala> val ordered = toOrder.mapValues(iterable =>
  orderTemplate.foldLeft(Iterable.empty[Int])((a, i) =>
    if (iterable.toBuffer.contains(i)) a.toBuffer :+ i
    else a
  )
)
ordered: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Iterable[Int]] = Map(1 -> ArrayBuffer(5, 2, 4, 6, 3))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This solution also works well :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I got.

```
val lst = List(1,5,7,2,4,8,6,3)
val itr = Iterable(2,3,4,5,6)

itr.map(x => (lst.indexOf(x), x))
   .toArray
   .sorted
   .map(_._2)
   .toIterable       // res0: Iterable[Int] = WrappedArray(5, 2, 4, 6, 3)
```

1. I coupled each entry with its relative index in the full list.
2. Can't sort iterables so went with `Array` (for no particular reason).
3. Tuples sorting defaults to the first element.
4. Remove the indexes.
5. Back to `Iterable`.

Comment: Thank you. Works awesome :)